# React Native - Cannot call a function between <Text>

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I'm new in React Native.

I want to call a function to format thousand separator of a value. Here my piece of code :

**Constructor :**

```
 this.state = {
            myValue: 10000000000,
 }
```

**Render :**

```
<Text> {Util.formatValueWithThousandSeparator(this.state.myValue)}</Text>
```

**Util :**

```
formatValueWithThousandSeparator: async(plainValue) => {
        let formatFloat = parseFloat(plainValue);
        formatFloat = Math.floor(formatFloat);
        let formatted = 0;

        if (Platform.OS === 'ios'){
            formatted = await formatFloat.toLocaleString('en-US', {minimumFractionDigits: 0});
        } else {
            formatted = await formatFloat.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
        }

        return formatted;
    }
```

**Error Message :**

```
Invariant violation: Object are not valid as react child (found: object with keys). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

**My Question :**

> How to best solution to achieve what i do? (format thousand separator
>   before it show up)

Comment: Starting Text tag is not closed, that's a typo?

Comment: Sorry, that's my fault when i copy paste and editing on the post. My code use close tag. I already update my post. thank you.

Comment: Your welcome. You will have an array of numbers to format. right ?

Comment: no. Only single number. Look to my state in constructor : myValue: 10000000000,

Comment: I think that function might be returning an object. check with returning typeof formatted, and you can also put await is not in try catch block, to check if it is causing error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just remove the async - await stuff I think is useless in that case. The methods you use are synchronous.

I am not very sure but I think due to that React tries to render a promise before is resolved.